# Add custom elements to sns.kdeplot legend

Tags: python, seaborn

I'd like to add some custom elements to an existing legend generated in Seaborn. This is my try which is not working:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))

sns.kdeplot(
    x=np.random.normal(0, 20, size=1000),
    ax=ax,
    hue=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000, p=[.1, .9]), 
    common_norm=False,
    fill=True,
)

legend_elements = [
            Line2D([0], [0], color="k", label="xxx"),
            Line2D([0], [0], color="k", ls=":", label="yyy"),
        ]

h = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(handles=h + legend_elements, loc="upper right" )
```

Problem 1: What I'm trying to do is capture the existing handles and labels from the ax, append the customs one, and setting them back, so I display the whole stuff. But I got errors on this.

Problem 2: I noticed that, if after showing the kdeplot I try to execute ax.legend(), it gives me the warning "No handles with labels found to put in legend", which is odd as I do see a handle with labels in the plot. Why is the reason?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a quick note: `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` would return both the handles and the labels, so you'd need to catch both (e.g. `h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`).

Now, `sns.kdeplot` doesn't use a standard matplotlib legend, but creates a custom one.  With such a custom legend, matplotlib's `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` doesn't work.

Instead, you can grab the handles of those legend elements directly from the existing legend: `ax.legend_.legendHandles`.  As these handles don't have labels incorporated, you also need to grab those from `ax.legend_.texts`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))

sns.kdeplot(
    x=np.random.normal(1, 20, size=1000).cumsum(),
    ax=ax,
    hue=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000, p=[.1, .9]),
    common_norm=False,
    fill=True,
)

extra_legend_elements = [
    Line2D([0], [0], color="k", label="xxx"),
    Line2D([0], [0], color="k", ls=":", label="yyy"),
]

handles = ax.legend_.legendHandles
for h, t in zip(handles, ax.legend_.texts):
    h.set_label(t.get_text())  # assign the legend labels to the handles
ax.legend(handles=handles + extra_legend_elements, loc="upper right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.kdeplot with extra legend elements]

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I believe this is the first time someone explains the details about the legend (I read so many pages!). Thanks again!